# UIImage with image set name

Tags: ios, uiimage

I want to instantiate an UIImage using an image set in the Assets. I tried this two approaches-

```
[UIImage imageNamed:myImageSetName]
```

and

```
[UIImage imageNamed:myImageSetName inBundle:nil compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil]
```

On both the occasion it seems to return an image with resolution of 320*480, which is the resolution of the default image of the image set.I tried running on iPhone 6s plus (11.3) and iPad pro 12.9 inch (11.3) simulators. So I am expecting the resolutions to be much different than this.

How should I get the image with proper resolution as per the device/OS? Or am I assuming something wrong?

Comment: have you added 3 images with different size in image assets ?

Comment: Yes I have full image set with different resolution images. I have all the cells of the xcode grid filled up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is as expected.
If you want the real image size on the current device, you need to take the screen resolution into accout.

Like for example with: `UIScreen.mainScreen().scale`
Or for calculation you can just use the x2 or x3 depending on your device.

So for the iPhone 6s plus it would be (2 x 320) * (2 x 480)

For displaying, iOS is handling that for you if you have all image assets setup.

For getting the actual image size, you need to take the scaling into the calculation:
`If you multiply the logical size of the image (stored in the size property) by the value in this property, you get the dimensions of the image in pixels.`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624110-scale

Comment: Well, I'm assuming the image instantiated using the imageset name will have proper image loaded with resolution as per the device. So for iPhone 6 plus in your example I'm expecting the instantiated UI image to be of 640*960. But after instantiating if I log the resolution of the UIImage, I'm always getting 320*480. Is there anyway to get it handled by iOS while instantiating the UIImage?

Comment: this is just a missunderstanding of the log of image.size. It will always show you the resolution of the 1x scale... your actual image size is `image.size * image.scale`. Also see the documentation on image.scale: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624110-scale

Answer (score 0):

You can use an app named App Icon Gear on your mac. And use it will cut the image to the wanted size you wish. Try it , may help you. Or check out some constraint things about your imageView.